# Why I can't run the same command that is my script of package.json without calling the script?

Tags: node.js, package.json

Why I can't run a command exactly the same as it is in my package.json file?
Here is an example:

**Package.json**

```json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "test": "jest",
  ...
},
```

If I run "npm run test" jest works fine and my unit tests are executed.
But if I try to run jest without using the script in the package.json, I can't execute it.

When I run the command jest:

```
zsh: command not found: jest
```

I thought that when I'm at the directory of the project, I would be able to use the same scripts as the project, without having to add it to the scripts and calling it via npm or yarn.

Comment: It's right there in the documentation: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts#path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, if you can't use jest by typing it's name, it's mean that jest is locally added, you can run locals commands from two ways, one with `./node_modules/.bin/jest` wich will invoke the jest command, and the second, `npx jest` wich will invoke jest too.
For the script field, As explained in the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts#path):

> If you depend on modules that define executable scripts, like test suites, then those executables will be added to the PATH for executing the scripts.

So, when you execute `npm run test`, npm will update your path to access to jest which is exported into the `node_modules/.bin directory` on npm install.